# Abstracting dispatch_async calls in a reusable way

Tags: ios

I'm trying to get better at creating more reusable pieces of code.  Currently in our app, we have a DataManager singleton that all the calls to the database go through.  So for an expensive lookup to the database, I want to put that call in a nested dispatch_async block to not block the main thread.  So currently,

In ViewControllerA:

```
dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{
  NSArray *array = [DataManager myExpensiveMethodCall];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self setEvents:array];
  });
});
```

I was wondering if there was a way to better abstract this type of "pattern."  I've seen it in Apple's sample code, and I basically do this type of nested dispatch_async call whenever I need to do an expensive method followed by an update to the UI.  I was just curious if it's "ok" to just put this type of code in whichever ViewController needs to do this kind of thing, or if there was a better way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a .h file put this outside of any @interface

```
typedef void(^MyBlockType)(void);
```

In your .m file, you could use somthing like this

```
+(void)doAsyncWithBlock:(MyBlockType)asyncBlock andSyncBlock:(MyBlockType)syncBlock
{
    dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{
        if( asyncBlock != nil )
        {
            asyncBlock();
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if( syncBlock != nil )
            {
                syncBlock();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do this, and the main advantage I see is that you can remove a dependence on GCD and keep most of your code agnostic of your primary concurrency technology.

I think it's reasonable to start a new class that has the responsibility for managing the dispatch of your asynchronous work units and coordinating their callbacks, rather than add this into a view controller class. Such an object could later maintain custom dispatch queues or `NSOperationQueue`s or whatever future technology comes along. I'm imagining something with a default instance that also provides an API to dispatch blocks agnostic of the underlying threading technology. A possible example using GCD follows:

```
typedef void(^AsynchronousWorkManagerBlock)();

@interface AsynchronousWorkManager : NSObject

+ (AsynchronousWorkManager *)defaultManager;

- (void)executeInBackground:(AsynchronousWorkManagerBlock)backgroundBlock
     withMainThreadCallback:(AsynchronousWorkManagerBlock)callbackBlock;

@end


@implementation AsynchronousWorkManager

+ (AsynchronousWorkManager *)defaultManager
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static AsynchronousWorkManager *DefaultManager = nil;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        DefaultManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return DefaultManager;
}

- (void)executeInBackground:(AsynchronousWorkManagerBlock)backgroundBlock
     withMainThreadCallback:(AsynchronousWorkManagerBlock)callbackBlock
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        backgroundBlock();
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), callbackBlock);
    });
}

@end
```

Client code could call it like so:

```
[[AsynchronousWorkManager defaultManager] executeInBackground:^{
                                            NSLog(@"This code is happening in the background");
                                        }
                                      withMainThreadCallback:^{
                                            NSLog(@"This code is happening on the main thread");
                                        }];

[[AsynchronousWorkManager defaultManager] executeInBackground:^{
                                            sleep(3);
                                        }
                                      withMainThreadCallback:^{
                                          NSLog(@"Done Sleeping");
                                      }];
```

Later, if you decided to switch to using `NSOperationQueue` instead of GCD, it would be straightforward to change without changing the API, as in the following example implementation:

```
@interface AsynchronousWorkManager ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;

@end


@implementation AsynchronousWorkManager

+ (AsynchronousWorkManager *)defaultManager
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static AsynchronousWorkManager *DefaultManager = nil;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        DefaultManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return DefaultManager;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)executeInBackground:(AsynchronousWorkManagerBlock)backgroundBlock
     withMainThreadCallback:(AsynchronousWorkManagerBlock)callbackBlock
{
    NSBlockOperation *blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:backgroundBlock];
    blockOperation.completionBlock = ^{ [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:callbackBlock]; };

    [self.operationQueue addOperation:blockOperation];
}

@end
```

I'm not totally sure how necessary this is, but since it can be accomplished without much code I'd judge it as possibly worthwhile, and not just an exercise in over-engineering. If your application makes extensive use of different priority queues or more specialized GCD features I'd be wary of moving to this due to the possibility of introducing a leaky abstraction without truly gaining any underlying implementation flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I typically define these two functions. They make the code more compact, and follow the pattern I use where you don't want to block the main thread (hence the RUN_ON_BACKGROUND_THREAD call is asynchronous) but it's OK to block a background thread in order to update the main thread (hence the RUN_ON_UI_THREAD) call is synchronous. It also avoids deadlock by allowing the call to be executed directly if it was invoked from the main thread.

```
void RUN_ON_UI_THREAD(dispatch_block_t block)
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])
        block();
    else
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
}

void RUN_ON_BACKGROUND_THREAD(dispatch_block_t block)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), block);
}
```